# How to use a model that is already trained in SKLearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

Rather than having my model retrain every time I run my code, I just want to test how to classifier responds to certain inputs. Is there a way in SKLearn I can "export" my classifier, save it somewhere and then use it to predict over and over in future?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can serialize your model and save it to a file.

This is documented [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).

Keep in mind, that there may be problems if you reload a model which was trained with some other version of scikit-learn. Usually you will see a warning then.